# javascript array in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building a file management system for the web right now. 
But I have some problems with javascript array's.

In the system there is an opportunity to add labels to file's.
In javascript I want to have the ID and the value's of the labels with the fileId in 1 array.(as below).
I also want the FileId and the LabelId not as the index of the array's. Because the FileId and labelId can be a realy high number. And then I have an array full of undefined items.

Here an example of how I would like to have it:

`array[FileId][labelId,labelValue]`

If you have an solution please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form structure like this:

```
arr = [{FieldId:fid_value, Labels:[{labelId:lid_value, labelValue:label_text}]}]
```

Basically, an array with objects. Each object contains two fields: field id and labels.
Labels is an array with objects also. Each object has label id and label value property.

Code to create new items might be like this:

```
arr = array();
fieldObj = {FieldId:fid_value, Labels:[]};
fieldObj.Labels.push({labelId:lid_value, labelValue:label_text});
fieldObj.Labels.push({labelId:lid_value, labelValue:label_text});
fieldObj.Labels.push({labelId:lid_value, labelValue:label_text});
...
arr.push(fieldObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but array within array is possible...

```
a = []
a.push('a')

Result:
["a"]
a.push(['hello','world'])

Result:
["a", 
 Array[2]
   0: "hello"
   1: "world"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want objects instead of arrays:

```
var obj = {};

obj["fieldName"] = {label: "labelname", labelId: 1234};
```

Then you can access this data as:

```
obj["fieldName"].label
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an object

```
var data = {};
data["item1"] = { "labelId" : "foo1", "labelValue" : "bar1" };
data["item2"] = { "labelId" : "foo2", "labelValue" : "bar2" };
console.log(data.item1.labelId);
```

There are plenty of ways you can strcture the object, it is normally better to use an object than to remember that index 0 is the id and that index 1 is a value.

Answer (score 0):

Use should use objects as well as arrays:

```
var root = [{
        id: '12345',
        metadata: {
            label: 'foo',
        },
        type: 'folder',
        name: 'Folder Name',
        children: [...]
    }
];
```

Now, you can iterate through the folders and files in your root:

```
for (var i = 0; i < root.length; i++) {
    var item = root[i];

    console.log(item.type, item.name, item.id);
}
```